# Export to Excel to be set for a single report in jasperserver 4.5

Tags: jasperserver

I am working on Jasper server 4.5 version.
   I need to know the details on whether i can set the Export to Excel for a report. 
   In more details all that i need is to have only one export option available for that report.
   But at the same time the changes done for this report should not affect the export options of other reports.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Sarakartik

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can export your reports as .xls or .xlsx files. If you are using 4.5 professional, check out the JasperReports Server User Guide in the documentation. There is a section on navigating and exporting reports. JasperReports Server allows you to export reports in many formats.

As for report-specific export options: because the exporting buttons are at the application level and not unique to each report, I think it might be difficult to enable only Excel exports for one report and not have that flow over into your other reports without extreme customization. But maybe someone else can offer a suggestion.